# How do I stop apps from losing their context when I switch to other apps?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a couple of apps that I use and when I leave them they always lose context.

Eg. I use CityMapper and it AWLAYS refreshes when I go back to the app.

I want my apps to behave like they used too ie if I am on a screen I want them to stay on that screen.

Update: iPhone 6

Comment: That is a bug with the app then. It is up to the app to keep its context when switched out, There will be an Apple Developer note explaining this

Comment: Even Safari does it: refreshes a web page

Comment: Hmm not for me - I have switched to other apps to get the password for pasting in and Safari has kept the half filled in form. So I think we need to know a bit more about the issue you have with Safari

Comment: ..& what iOS/device

Comment: Your device might have a problem with its RAM (maybe it's too full!) and can't store the application in the Active state. Try cleaning your RAM and please tell us what model of iPhone you use.

Comment: How to clean ram?

Comment: Here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpzgY4iWT3Q (Try that, then comment back with `@JohnRamos` somewhere in your comment so I get notified) and I can help you more.